# Salesforce Triggered Sends contain rows with no Object/Action

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I have a number of records in my "Salesforce Triggered Sends" page that contain no Object or Action values, they however do have emails sent from them.

Can anyone explain where they come from or how I can determine if they are really active or not? (they appear to be deactivated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are triggered sends that were created as a result of the Journey Builder Integration with Salesforce.

If you create a Journey using Salesforce Data as your Entry Source, and then have an email send in this Journey, a triggered send is created to manage this.  All object/action information that would normally be included is managed via Flows and Process Builder.